# How to get only the unit names using systemctl?

Tags: regular-expression, systemctl, container

When I do

```
systemctl list-units --all --state=loaded
```

I get the output in of each unit with columns as

```
UNIT     LOAD   ACTIVE   SUB       DESCRIPTION
```

I need only the `UNIT` in output.

I tried adding `--property=UNIT` but it still prints all columns.
Tried `--output=json-pretty` , didn't work.

I have to match a particular unit in the output but my regex is failing so it'll be helpful if I get only the list of units so it'll be easy to compare strings.

The regex I am using is `fgrep "input_from_user".service`

Any suggestion on regex or the command?

Comment: You're not using any regex there, `fgrep` is operating with strings not with regex. What are you trying to accomplish actually? I suspect you're trying to filter units by `input_from_user` in which case `systemctl list-units \*input_from_user\* --quiet` would do.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have the JSON output, you could use `jq` or Python or anything that understands JSON. For example, filtering using `jq`:

```
systemctl list-units --output json |
  jq -r --arg pattern input_from_user '.[].unit | select(test($pattern))'
```

This is not documented, but [this was added in May 2020](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/15701/) as a general feature converting tabular output to JSON; a `git grep output_table` indicates it should work for `list-units`, `list-unit-files` and `list-machines`.

Example:

```
% systemctl list-units --output json | jq -r --arg pattern network '.[].unit | select(test($pattern))'
network-online.target
network.target
```

Comment: Unfortunately `--output json` (and the entire `--output`) is only for the journal lines, not for the systemctl output itself.

Comment: @intelfx oh? And yet, this is what I get: `% systemctl list-units --output json |
 jq . | head` =>                                             `[
  {
    "unit": "proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.automount",
    "load": "loaded",
    "active": "active",
    "sub": "waiting",
    "description": "Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point"
  },`. Maybe test before making such assertions?

Comment: I cross-checked with the docs. Looks like they are inaccurate, apologies. Would you mind editing your answer just a bit (maybe add a note about the docs being out of date) so that I could retract the vote?

Comment: @intelfx edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try this oneliner:

```
systemctl show '*' --state=loaded --property=Id --value --no-pager | grep . | sort | uniq
```

### Explanation

- [`systemctl` provides the `show` command](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#show%20PATTERN%E2%80%A6%7CJOB%E2%80%A6):

  - `'*'` selects all units (to my observation). Without `'*'`, `systemctl show` would just *show* information for the systemd manager itself, not for the units managed by it.
  - `--state=loaded` selects only those *units* which are in the *loaded* state, as specified by your question (... each selected unit's load state can be added to the output by adding `--property=LoadState`)
  - `--property=Id` adds the [unit name (`Id`)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/org.freedesktop.systemd1.html#Properties1) to the output (also see the [`--property` documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#-p)).
  - [`--value`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#--value) removes the property *keys* from the output, and only shows the property *values* (i.e, `Id=foo.service` becomes `foo.service`)
  - [`--no-pager`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#--no-pager) instructs `systemctl` not to use a pager (... added just in case `systemctl` doesn't notice that automatically it is used within a pipe)
- `systemctl show ...`'s output is then piped through `... | grep . | sort | uniq`:

  - `grep .` filters away any empty newlines. This makes downstream processing more robust
  - `sort` sorts all unit names alphabetically
  - `uniq` makes sure every unit name is listed at most once (added just in case).